# INSTALL AND CONFIGURE SSL ON APACHE 2.4.1 (freebsd)

Tags: apache, ssl, freebsd

It's been days since I did not get to the top of the thing.
I already have certificates.
I would like to know where to place them, and what files to edit / create to run the site in **https**.
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, look at `SSLCertificateChainFile` in file `/usr/local/etc/apache24/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`

Uncomment the two lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/apache24/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/etc/apache24/server.key"
```

Put the certificate and the private key in the corresponding files.